Image Upload Fails using multipart on Android with "TypeError: Network request failed" Error Using Fetch in Expo App, Works Fine on iOS
This is my first time developing an app using Expo and React Native. I have encountered an issue where uploading an image to a server using fetch and FormData fails on Android but works fine on iOS. The error message I receive on Android is:  ERROR  [TypeError: Network request failed].
All the other api endpoints are wokring fine but the only issue is with the image upload api.
Below is my code for the api call
const callUploadApi = async () => {
  try {
    const imageType = imgUri.endsWith(".jpg")
      ? "image/jpeg"
      : imgUri.endsWith(".png")
      ? "image/png"
      : imgUri.endsWith(".gif")
      ? "image/gif"
      : "image/jpeg";
    
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file", {
      uri: imgUri,
      type: imageType,
      name: imgUri.split("/").pop(), 
    });
    
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formdata,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    console.log("upload image requestOptions", JSON.stringify(requestOptions));

    const response = await fetch(
      `${SERVER_URL}/api/upload`,
      requestOptions
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResponse = await response.json();
      throw errorResponse;
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    const { fileUrl } = result.data;
    setImgUrl(fileUrl);

    console.log(result);
    Alert.alert("Upload Success", "Image uploaded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    Alert.alert("Upload Failed", "Image upload failed");
  }
};


I have verified that the server URL and API endpoint are correct. The issue only occurs on Android devices, whereas on iOS, the image is uploaded without any problems.
I've tried debugging this issue but haven't been able to pinpoint the cause. Here are some of the steps I've taken:

Checked necessary permissions in app.json.
Ensured the server accepts multipart form data.
Verified the image URI format and content type.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue or could provide insight into why this might be happening specifically on Android? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

